# Why the output of this program is unordered and written to stdout?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, stdout, stdin, stderr

In this program, the output is unordered and as `stdout` is linked to the terminal the output of `fprintf()` containing `stdout` is written to the terminal, but why the output of the `fprintf()` containing `stderr` also printed to the terminal? Rather it should be printed to the `stderr` file handle. Is `stderr` also linked to the terminal?

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "This is to stdout. ");
    fprintf(stderr, "This is to stderr. ");
    fprintf(stdout, "This is also to stdout. ");
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT** (in online compiler)

```
This is to stderr. This is to stdout. This is also to stdout.
```

Also I would like to ask one thing. Why the output is different in my `Visual Studio Code IDE`.

**VS CODE OUTPUT**

```
This is to stdout. This is to stderr. This is also to stdout.
```

Here VS CODE gives different output from the online compiler. Why it is so and how to fix this?

Comment: When run interactively from a normal terminal without redirection, standard error output goes to the terminal. There may be a difference in the buffering of the standard output and standard error output streams when the program starts. The standard output stream could be line buffered or fully buffered (it is supposed to be line buffered if a terminal is detected). The standard error stream could be non-buffered or line buffered.

Comment: You can add a call `fflush(stdout);` after the first `fprintf(stdout, ...)` and perhaps add a call `fflush(stderr);` after the `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.

Comment: Also tell me about the output we see in the Visual Studio Code. Why it is different as compared to the online compiler?

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder it has nothing to do with VS Code. It depends on the buffering mode. If stdout is non-buffered or the buffer size is smaller than the printed strings then the latter output will be seen

Comment: Is there any way to check if it is buffered or not on my system?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to check the buffering mode, but you can change the buffering mode of a stream with `setvbuf`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: “The standard output stream could be line buffered or fully buffered”: When known to be going to a terminal, standard output should be line buffered or unbuffered, not fully buffered. Per C 2018 7.21.3 7, it should be fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C implementation, when output is to a terminal, `stdout` is *line buffered*, and `stderr` is *unbuffered*. This means that output to `stderr` is sent to the terminal immediately, whereas output to `stdout` is sent only when:

- a new-line character is sent,
- input is requested from the user<sup>1</sup> (so a prompt sent on `stdout` will appear before the user is supposed to type a response),
- the buffer is full, or
- a buffer flush is requested (as with `fflush`).

When a stream is buffered, characters may be accumulated in a buffer and sent or received as a block when the buffer is full. Buffering is used because the operations to send or receive data have a large overhead, so executing them for each character sent, or each partial line, would be expensive in terms of resources such as execution time and energy. Sending many characters from a buffer in one operation is more efficient.

In addition to unbuffered and line buffered, there is also *fully buffered*, in which characters are intended to be sent or received only when the buffer is full. The C standard describes buffering in C 2018 7.21.3 3.

In 7.21.3 7, the standard tells us the standard error stream is not fully buffered. It may be unbuffered or line buffered. Your C implementation apparently chooses to make it unbuffered, so error messages will be written to the terminal immediately. That paragraph also tells us that standard input and standard output are fully buffered only if the stream “can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.” For example, if you redirect output to a file instead of the terminal, it does not refer to an interactive device, and it should be fully buffered. When output is known to be going to an interactive device, it should not be fully buffered. It may be line buffered or unbuffered, and your C implementation apparently chooses to make it line buffered.

If you modify the program to include `\n` at the end of each string it prints, you will see them in order, because the unbuffered and line buffered streams will print each complete line (characters ending with a new-line character) in order.

You can also use `setvbuf` to change the buffering mode of a stream after it is open and before any other operation is performed on it. For example, to set `stdout` to unbuffered, you can use:

```
int result = setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
if (result != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, setvbuf returned %d.\n", result);
```

`setvbuf` is specified in C 2018 7.21.5.6. `_IOFBF` requests fully buffered, and `_IOLBF` requests line buffered. (The second and fourth parameters are for providing your own array to use as the buffer and its length.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, requesting input (as by calling `fgetc` or `scanf`) on an unbuffered stream or on a line buffered stream that “requires the transmission of characters from the host environment” will trigger flushing of line buffered output.

Answer (score -1):

**@Eric shows me that my answer is wrong. :(**

Stdout and stderr are logically different. It is possible redirect them to different devices, like a printer and a screen.
The sequence of instructions has to follow the order implied by the semicolons of your program.
Thus, the first string is sent to stdout. After that,  the second string is sent to stderr.
After that,  the third string is sent to stdout.

If you sent strings to a screen and a printer, the strings are sent to the respective ports, but the time employed by these devices in doing their respective printings is independent, and it is out of the control of your program.
Consider the case of a printer having pending work.

However you have stderr and stdout directed by default to the same device: the screen.
This fact does not imply that the strings must be shown in order.
The Operating System may treat the requests of printing on stderr and on stdout in a different manner.
The strings are sent logically to different devices that, phisically resulted the same,  but the OS could give priority to stderr for some reason.
The stderr stream is used to inform error messages.
This is a spetial and critical situation. The intent is that the text arrive as soon as possible, so the characters are not buffered, and they are sent as soon as they arrive.
On the other hand, text sent to stdout is buffered, so that chatacters are sent in chunks or as entire lines.
If the OS has detected a that a text is sent to stderr, perhaps it gives priority to it.

The solution would be to use stderr only when a critical error takes place.

Comment: The buffering is part of the C standard library. Buffered data is not “sent to the respective ports” when `fprintf` is called, and it is not out of the control of your program—your program can transmit the data from **its** buffer to the device by using `fflush`, and it will appear as soon as possible. This is a function of the C standard library, not of the operating system.

Comment: Thank you by your corrections. I realize that I had wrong beliefs. However, I still have doubts about using `fflush` in `stdout`.

Comment: C 2018 7.21.5.2 specifies that `fflush` causes buffered data for an output or update stream to be delivered, and it does not indicate any special treatment or exception for `stdout`. Perhaps your reluctance is related to `fflush(stdin)`? That is not defined by the C standard, since it is an input stream. Old versions of Microsoft software defined it, but people on Stack Overflow kept saying not to use it.

Comment: @Eric Yes, my doubts are related to `fflush(stdin)`. You are being my teacher today, for free. Thank you for your patience.